# How to Fix Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property 'innerHTML'

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i want to search data between tow dates but occurring same error again and again i have tried multiple searches and techniques but i am stuck i just keep getting error this error and dont know what to do to resolve this 
there is search button above the table which get two dates from user and from those dates data is search and displayed again its kind filteration of data by dates

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info  " style="font-size:17px; margin-left:548px; margin-top:-63px;" onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
     <table id="worksheet-list" class="table table-responsive">


                <thead >

                    <tr class="table table-primary">

                        <th>
                            @*@Html.Label("SNo")*@
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.Label("Project")
                        </th>


                        <th>
                            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hours)*@
                            Hours
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)*@
                            Date
                        </th>

                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                @*@foreach (var item in Model)*@
                @for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++)

                {
                    //count++;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @count
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.Name)*@
                            ASP.NET
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)*@
                            5 Hours
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)*@
                            6/8/2018
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                            @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>*@
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>



                    </tr>
                }

            </table> 


<script>
 function myFunction() {
        var from = document.getElementById("date-from");
        var to = document.getElementById("date-to");
        var table = document.getElementById("worksheet-list");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var td;
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerHTML;

            var d1 = from.split("/");
            var d2 = to.split("/");
            var c = td.split("/");

            var from = new Date(d1[0], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1, d1[2]);
            var to = new Date(d2[0], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1, d2[2]);
            var check = new Date(c[0], parseInt(c[1]) - 1, c[2]);
            if (check >= from && check <= to) {

                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {

                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: It means that this `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]` is undefined.  We can't help without seeing the table `#worksheet-list`

Comment: i have given a complete code now

Answer (score 0):

Where you get the table rows with `getElementsByTagName("tr")`, you will also get the row in the `thead` element, which has no child `td` elements.

The simplest way to fix your problem is to ignore the first table row by starting your loop at 1...

```
for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
```

If you wanted to, you could put a sense check in your code...

```
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // if this row has no 3rd td then continue the loop
    if (td.length < 4) continue;

    td = td[3];
```